# Table column width and overflow settings are not working

Tags: html, css

in my stylesheet:

```
table.fixed { table-layout:fixed; }
table.fixed td, th { overflow: hidden; }
```

in my view:

```
<table class="fixed">
  <col width="20px" />
  <col width="300px" />
  <col width="50px" />
  <% @reviewers.each do |r| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= r.first_name %></td>
      <td><%= r.last_name %></td>
      <td><%= r.email %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

1. I set the first column width too
   narrow to test the overflow.
2. I set the second column width too
   long to test whether the column
   width is set.

Neither overflow or column width is working in Firefox or Safari.

Thanks.

**Update**
Working Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/46jXM/

Comment: +1 for using _whose_ in the question.  We should get a fiddle for this...

Comment: @pixelbobby. Feel better? :=] Don't understand the reference to a fiddle :=/

Comment: I created a fiddle for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/46jXM/

Comment: Hey, @pixelbobby. Ah... that fiddle. Just found fiddle yesterday. I didn't think it was that much code so didn't use it. You use it for all your posts that include code on SO?

Comment: @pixelbobby, sizing and overflow don't work on the example in fiddle either.

Comment: Yeah, I try to... even if it's just basic HTML/CSS. @Midas might have a good answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `word-wrap:break-word`. But you'll have to specify a width for the table.

```
table.fixed { table-layout:fixed; word-wrap:break-word; width:100% }
```

You can also leave the `word-wrap:break-word`, but then the text in the different columns overlaps.

Comment: Hey, @Midas. You were right,... had to specify the width for the whole table, not just the columns. Since i was trying to hide the overflow, i didn't use the word wrap break-word.